# jenkins pipeline sh not working for few commands

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to run the following command to scan dotnet core project using sonarqube in Jenkins pipeline

```
    sh "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:projectkey1"
    sh "dotnet build"
    sh "dotnet sonarscanner end"
```

Gives me the following error

```
    + dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:projectkey1
    No executable found matching command "dotnet-sonarscanner"
```

I can login to the same server as user jenkins and run the same command without any issues. 
Please help

Comment: you would need to add the global tool directory to your path. Check where it is installed and add this directory. In my case it is installed in `/root/.dotnet/tools`. Another question what kind of jenkins slave you are running against?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the dotnet tools path in the Jenkins pipeline.

Try:

> sh "export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/.dotnet/tools"

before your steps in the pipeline:

> sh "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:projectkey1"
>   sh "dotnet build"
>   sh "dotnet sonarscanner end"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the user account being used for the agent in the pipeline is the same one that you've logged into and installed the `sonarscanner` global CLI tool on. Because .NET Core Global Tools are user-specific, it won't be available is the users are different.

If you're certain it's the same user, then it's likely caused by [cmd.exe needing to be restarted](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8368).

If all else fails, [you can use `SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll` for .NET Core](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) instead of the global CLI tool.

Comment: I am running dotnet core on Ubuntu machine. All the other dotnet commands work. Except this

Comment: `donet-sonarscanner` isn't a standard `dotnet` CLI command, it's an installed [global tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools). This is why it behaves differently.